# function not running if target is a child

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried developing a `script` which runs a function whenever an element is clicked (this includes the `children` being clicked).

In this case, the page just needs to alert `"done"`. However, for some reason -
despite it all being correctly programmed (at least as far as I'm aware) - it still doesn't want work as expected.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="/profile.php" class="nav-user-content_profile" onclick="return false;">
    <div class="_user-pfp">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
    </div>
    <div class="_user-name">
        <span>Username</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
document.onclick = function(e){ // on document click
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // get all links on page

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        if(e.target === links[i]){ // if clicked link is parent
            e.preventDefault(); // do not redirect
            alert("done"); // alert "done" (this all works)
        } else {
            for(var x = 0; x < links[i].children.length; x++){
                if(e.target === links[i].children[x]){ // if clicked link is child
                    e.preventDefault(); // do not redirect
                    alert("done"); // alert "done" (this does not work)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle for reference: [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xy2yoLs4/1/)

All help is appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: Why don't you just check the `e.target`, if it's a link, you can print "done", if not check parent of `e.target` with a recursive function that checks the parent until it finds a `<a>` or reaches body/html?

Comment: @andeersg that is exactly what I'm doing...

Comment: No, you loop through all links on the page and compare then with the clicked element. I can try to create an answer of what I mean :)

Comment: @andeersg go for it! might just earn you a few points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition at second `for` loop evaluates to `false` due to `<html>` not being one of the `.children` of the single `<a>` element in the `document`.

When the `document` is clicked outside of the bounds of the sole `<a>` element that click is made onto the `<html>` element.

---

Using the existing code you can utilize [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) with selector `"a"`

```
else { if (e.target.closest("a") !== null) { // do stuff } }
```

or check if an `<a>` element is in `e.path`

Comment: I know I shouldn't be going against someone with almost 50 times my reputation (and thank you for the help btw :) ), but shouldn't this be a comment as opposed to an answer?

Comment: @GROVER. Not sure what you mean? You knew before posting the Question that clicking outside of the `<a>` element would not be clicking on any `.children` of the `<a>` element, but rather, would be a click onto the root node of the `document`:`<html>`? You should be able to adjust the code from there to check if the element tag name is `HTML`, or just use the `else` block.

Comment: But, the user is clicking **inside** the element (on the children), and the alert is not being shown. It only works if the element is clicked (but not the children).

Comment: The `<img>` element is not included in the `.children` of the `<a>` element. The `<img>` element is a child element of a `<div>` element. Using the existing code you would need to use yet another loop to iterate the `.children` of the `<div>` child element of the parent `<a>` element

Comment: Well then how would I get around this problem? Because I'm clueless at this point lol

Comment: Using the existing code you can utilize [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) with selector `"a"` `else {
      if (e.target.closest("a") !== null) {      
        // do stuff
      }
    }` or check if an `<a>` element is in `e.path`

Comment: Should make this an answer, because it fixed my problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your problem correctly you want to do something when `<a>` is clicked, and also of children of `<a>` is clicked.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'A') {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Link clicked');
  }
  else {
    const el = isParentLink(e.target);
    if (el.tagName == 'A') {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Parent is a link');
    }
  }
});

function isParentLink(node) {
  if (node.tagName == 'A') {
    return node;
  }
  return isParentLink(node.parentElement);
}
```

This snippet checks if target is an anchor element, and if not it checks the parents, until it reaches the html tag.

Comment: Error thrown if no element is clicked: `Cannot read property 'tagName' of null`

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce that on CodePen, but you can add `if (!e.target) { return;} ` at the beginning of the click function to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the best approach to what you want.
You're already searching for `<a>`, then search for the tag you've clicked inside of each `<a>` you've found.

```js
document.onclick = function(e){ // on document click
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // get all links on page
  
    for(var link of links){ //loop through each a element found
      var tags = link.getElementsByTagName(e.target.tagName); //get all tags within "link" with the same tag as the selected element
      for(var tag of tags){
        if(e.target === tag){
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("done");
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="/profile.php" class="nav-user-content_profile" onclick="return false;">
    <div class="_user-pfp">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
    </div>
    <div class="_user-name">
        <span>Username</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Or, you can use recursion, your code only looks for children, but what about children's children? See the example:

```js
document.onclick = function(e){ // on document click
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // get all links on page

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        if(e.target === links[i]){ // if clicked link is parent
            e.preventDefault(); // do not redirect
            alert("done"); // alert "done" (this all works)
        } else {
            searchChildren(e, links[i]);
        }
    }
}

function searchChildren(e, parent){
  for(var x = 0; x < parent.children.length; x++){
    if(e.target === parent.children[x]){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("done");
      break;
    }else if(parent.children[x].hasChildNodes()){
      searchChildren(e, parent.children[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="/profile.php" class="nav-user-content_profile" onclick="return false;">
    <div class="_user-pfp">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
    </div>
    <div class="_user-name">
        <span>Username</span>
    </div>
</a>
```